# The regular color of my website shows up when I refresh my page in dark mode

Tags: javascript, local-storage

The problem I am having now is that the regular color of my website shows up when I re-enter my webpage before switching to the dark mode. I am using localstorage to remember that a user has selected the dark mode and the dark mode CSS is stored in a separate css file.

I was looking for some answers on how to display the website after the CSS has fully loaded, but none of the provided answers worked in my case.

I was thinking about utilizing the onload function in the body of the html to check which stylesheet should be applied but I don't know how to do it properly.

Here is the code I use to set the dark mode and then to store that information in the localStorage:

```
function toggleStyles() {
var style = document.getElementById("style");
var btn = document.getElementById("darkModeBtn");
if (btn.innerHTML==="Light Mode") {
style.setAttribute('href', "style.css");
btn.innerHTML = "Dark Mode";
localStorage.setItem("mode", "light");
mode = localStorage.getItem("mode");

} else {
style.setAttribute('href', "styleDarkMode.css");
btn.innerHTML = "Light Mode";
localStorage.setItem("mode", "dark");
mode = localStorage.getItem("mode");
}
}

let mode;
mode = localStorage.getItem("mode");

if (mode === "dark"){

document.getElementById("style").setAttribute('href',     
"styleDarkMode.css");
document.getElementById("darkModeBtn").innerHTML = "Light Mode";

} else {

document.getElementById("style").setAttribute('href', 
"style.css");
document.getElementById("darkModeBtn").innerHTML = "Dark Mode";
}
```

When I refresh or re-enter the page, for a split second, the page is in its regular colors. What can I do to load it fully in the dark mode?

Also, sometimes it first loads (for less than a second) as a plain html file before applying all the necessary css styles. Any ideas on how to resolve that second problem?

Comment: Don't set the style sheef references using JavaScript, then the page won't flash up un-styled. Alternatively, set a default/empty style sheet (that shows a generic loading screen or something and hides the rest) statically and then load the actual style sheet using JS.

Comment: @JoachimSauer the second option, with the static loading page, seems like a good idea to me. How could I do that to hide the page and then show it once it is fully loaded? Should I use the "onload" function?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are loading the stylesheets using javascript. A possible solution is to have one stylesheet (style.css) in which you set different colors for the light/dark theme. Then, using classes, you can set the class of your body to something like '.darkbody' or '.lightbody'.

This way, the CSS isn't loaded after the page has loaded, and it probably flashes less. HOWEVER: There still is a possibility of flashing, since the class isn't set immediately after the page is loaded.

Comment: Would it help if I first showed a simple loading page before the content of my page fully loads? That is, would the flashing stop? In theory, I think it is a good idea, don't you?

Comment: I think the best thing to do is to use one stylesheet, loaders tend to make users leave a site, since every time they load a page they have to wait on loader. Maybe this article can provide help: https://dev.to/ananyaneogi/create-a-dark-light-mode-switch-with-css-variables-34l8